# Loading DefaultComboBoxModel using Swing Worker

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to load JComboBox values using SwingWorker in a trigger of Button. But clicking the button won't load the values in my JComboBox. I send the data via `publish()` method and receives it using `process()`. But mapping elements to my `JComboBox` won't set the model. Any reasons why?

```
private Map<JComboBox, DefaultComboBoxModel> puta()
{
    Map<JComboBox, DefaultComboBoxModel> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(view.getCb(), (DefaultComboBoxModel)view.getCb().getModel());
    return map;
}

class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        //Show Internal Frame
        createFrame();

        new ComboBoxWorker(puta()).execute();
    }

}

 private class ComboBoxWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, List>
 {
    public final Map<JComboBox, DefaultComboBoxModel> map;

    public ComboBoxWorker(Map<JComboBox, DefaultComboBoxModel> map)
    {
        this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception 
    {
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(model.setGender());

        publish(list);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List chunks) 
    {
        map.get(view.getCb()).addElement(chunks);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may not access swing components and their model from another thread than the EDT, but you're doing it by populating your combo box from doInBackground. There might be other problems, but your code is far from complete, so...

Comment: @JBNizet What I did I made a getter for each swing components and create a instance of class of it. Should I still wrap `run` method when creating another frame?

Comment: I have no idea of what you're talking about. How are getters to components relevant to your question? How is creating a jframe relevant to your question? Which run method are you talking about? Wrap it with what? Start your question from scratch and tell what you want to achieve, post a minimal but complete, runnable example showing the code you tried, explain what it is supposed to do and what it does instead.

Comment: You should read the SwingWorker tutorial to understand how it transfers data from the background thread to the EDT

Comment: Hi! @MadProgrammer. I just updated my code. I transfer my data via `publish()` method but unable to addElement in my ComboBox.